# Extjs databinding model properties to ui elements (textbox)

Tags: javascript, data-binding, frameworks, extjs

I need binding the model properties to view elements directly bidirectional way automatically stay sync. If I make a change in a textbox I need run bussiness logic in the related model, and model properties changes automatically refresh the related ui elements.

Im new in Extjs, but I guess it doesnt support it, JQXB seem to be the right way, does anyone could point me a sample using JQXB with Extjs?

Comment: Technically Ext does support databinding ( Ext.data.store is rather robust imho )

Answer (score 0):

With jQXB it's very simple to stay in sync.

jQXB is striclty related to jQuery so I assume your needs can be satisfied only with jQXB and jQuery.(Extjs is no more required);

In your case you need only to use jQuery to catch textbox changes and then, supposing your datamodel already binded to controls via jQXB datasource, invoke doBind method to refresh controls after changing data model.

At http://www.jqxb.altervista.org you can see in demos pages that already do something like that.
At http://jqxb.codeplex.com ( Download Section) you can examples and in Documentation Section you can find other examples.

Alternatively you can post an example of what you want to obtain or write directly a post or an email on jQXB site.

regards